# What's the difference between Where(lambda expr.) and First(lambda expr.) when I need to pick the first item?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'd like to know the difference between this two syntaxes:

```
return db.Contacts.First(x => x.ContactID == id)
```

That I've been using so far until I get an error "**Sequence contains no elements**". then I have to use the below one again.

```
return db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactID == id).First();
```

There must be a nuance I'm not getting right.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`First` is used to get the first element of a sequence, but it also takes a predicate to allow you to filter the IEnumerable sequence.

So `First` will return the first element of an `IEnumerable` with 1 or more results.

`First(Predicate)` will return the first element of results within an IEnumerable with 1 or more results.

If there are 0 elements when using `First` you'll get the error *Sequence contains no elements*. If you're expecting there to be 0 results, you should use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). `FirstOrDefault` can also take a predicate as well, i.e.

```
// Will return null if there are no elements with a matching contact Id
return db.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == id);
```

Comment: Why First would return more than 1 result?

Comment: @Richard77 - First won't ever return more than 1 result. It'll always return 1 result.